# How to add new class in div via javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hello Everyone i am using wordpress slider but i want to add new class in slider `<li>` via javascript.

```
<div class="wp-slider">
 <ul>
 <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript :

```
document.querySelector('.wp-slider ul li').classList.add('MyClass')
```

(or in JQuery :)

```
$('.wp-slider ul li').addClass("MyClass")
```